# replace the matched string in a file with ref to multi line

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, sed

I want to replace the KEY value(Pods-myapp.release.xcconfig)  **15c66c8f-f855-461c-8b6f-5ecf94ea05e3** with **23c54c8g-f935-260c-2b9f-5cce93eb05d3** in my project file 'project.pbxproj'. The issue is same key is assigned for other configs. I tried to replace the key based on occurrence using sed. But I want to make sure replacing key value at right place even if the config (release, debug, enterprise) order changed in the file.

```
        baseConfigurationReference = DF7B54DFD1BD7EF176BA3943 /* Pods-myapp.release.xcconfig */;
        buildSettings = {
                KEY = "15c66c8f-f855-461c-8b6f-5ecf94ea05e3";
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
.
.
.
    baseConfigurationReference = F997700201F34D7A8AEFA5E3 /* Pods-myapp.enterprise.xcconfig */;
            buildSettings = {
                KEY = "15c66c8f-f855-461c-8b6f-5ecf94ea05e3";
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
```

I tried to replace

```
export KEY='15c66c8f-f855-461c-8b6f-5ecf94ea05e3'
export RELEASE_APP_KEY='23c54c8g-f935-260c-2b9f-5cce93eb05d3'

sed -i '' "1/$KEY/s/$KEY/$RELEASE_APP_KEY/" project.pbxproj
```

How to replace the key value for the Release config if it is found at 2nd or nth occurrence.

```
    baseConfigurationReference = F997700201F34D7A8AEFA5E3 /* Pods-myapp.enterprise.xcconfig */;
            buildSettings = {
                KEY = "15c66c8f-f855-461c-8b6f-5ecf94ea05e3";
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
.
.
.
        baseConfigurationReference = DF7B54DFD1BD7EF176BA3943 /* Pods-myapp.release.xcconfig */;
        buildSettings = {
                KEY = "15c66c8f-f855-461c-8b6f-5ecf94ea05e3";
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
```

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Please read [mcve].  You should provide a sample input  with all cases, desired output and what you have tried.  Then we can help bridge the gab between your desired output and what you are getting form  your first version.

Comment: @Nic3500 Updated the question. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as the number of lines between the comment and then `KEY` are fixed at `2`, you can do that with `sed` as:

```
sed '/Pods-myapp.release.xcconfig/{n;n;/KEY/s/15c66c8f-f855-461c-8b6f-5ecf94ea05e3/23c54c8g-f935-260c-2b9f-5cce93eb05d3/;}'
```

or to shorten things you could assign your keys to variables and do:

```
k1=15c66c8f-f855-461c-8b6f-5ecf94ea05e3
k2=23c54c8g-f935-260c-2b9f-5cce93eb05d3
sed "/Pods-myapp.release.xcconfig/{n;n;/KEY/s/$k1/$k2/;}" project.pbxproj
```

**Explanation**

Basically the command above `/locate/{n;n;/match/s/k1/k2;}` where:

- `/locate/` locates the line containing `"Pods-myapp.release.xcconfig"` and then
- `{n;n;` reads (skips) two lines,
- `/match/` (optional) ensures the line contains `"KEY"`, then
- your normal substitute form where `k1` is replaced by `k2`.

**Example Use/Output**

Where the two different orderings of your file are in `project.pbxproj` and `project.pbxproj2` and the keys are in the variables `k1` and `k2`:

```
$ sed "/Pods-myapp.release.xcconfig/{n;n;/KEY/s/$k1/$k2/;}" project.pbxproj
        baseConfigurationReference = DF7B54DFD1BD7EF176BA3943 /* **Pods-myapp.release.xcconfig** */;
        buildSettings = {
                KEY = "23c54c8g-f935-260c-2b9f-5cce93eb05d3";
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
.
.
.
    baseConfigurationReference = F997700201F34D7A8AEFA5E3 /* Pods-myapp.enterprise.xcconfig */;
            buildSettings = {
                KEY = "15c66c8f-f855-461c-8b6f-5ecf94ea05e3";
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
```

and

```
$ sed "/Pods-myapp.release.xcconfig/{n;n;/KEY/s/$k1/$k2/;}" project.pbxproj2)
    baseConfigurationReference = F997700201F34D7A8AEFA5E3 /* Pods-myapp.enterprise.xcconfig */;
            buildSettings = {
                KEY = "15c66c8f-f855-461c-8b6f-5ecf94ea05e3";
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
.
.
.
        baseConfigurationReference = DF7B54DFD1BD7EF176BA3943 /* Pods-myapp.release.xcconfig */;
        buildSettings = {
                KEY = "23c54c8g-f935-260c-2b9f-5cce93eb05d3";
```

Comment: Thank you. @David C. Rankin,  what if KEY line is placed at different line within the buildSettings {...};
ex: 
baseConfigurationReference = DF7B54DFD1BD7EF176BA3943 /* **Pods-myapp.release.xcconfig** */;
buildSettings = {
        KEY = "23c54c8g-f935-260c-2b9f-5cce93eb05d3";
        ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
..
..
..
..
};

Comment: When you start dealing with variable line spacing of terms, etc.., then you really need to move to `awk`. `sed` is a *Stream EDitor* that is targeted a replacements within a line and is nowhere near as flexible as `awk` which is basically a separate programming language on its own that specializes in delimited fields within a record (line).